# Codigo de Barras Reportviewer c# con dataset de Mysql

Tags: c#, reportviewer, dataset, rdlc

Estimados en mi reporte (reportViewer) que lleno desde un Dataset y por Parametros tambien, quiero incluir un codigo de barras que me muestre un string que genero concatenando numeros. No se como incluir el codigo de Barras en el reporte.

Esto funciona perfecto pero no se como agregarle un codigo de barras al report1.rdlc

```
sql = "SELECT id_socio, apellido,nombre,tipodoc,nrodoc FROM tbl_socios WHERE id_club = 5";


            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, ConexionDB);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            ReportDataSource fuente;
            fuente = new ReportDataSource("tbl_socios", ds.Tables[0]);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(fuente);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "CapaPresentacion.Report1.rdlc";
            string t1 = Nombreclub
            string t2 = "Informe - Socios";
            string i1 = ControlPanel.varimagen;//C://Control Club/atenas.png";

            ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[3];
            parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("T1", t1);
            parameters[1] = new ReportParameter("T2", t2);
            parameters[2] = new ReportParameter("I1", i1, false);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);

            reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
            reportViewer1.Refresh();
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            ConexionDB.Close();
```

Estoy trabjando con Visual studio 2019 Community

Agradeceria mucho la ayuda que pueden brindarme.- Abrazo.-

Comment: En que parte del reporte iría el codigo de barras, además hay diferentes estándares de código de barra, cual quieres?

Comment: El codigo de barras iria en el cuerpo del Reporte1.rdlc supongo que debe ir en un campo imagen... Yo estoy usando y la libreria BarcodeLib y genere el codigo de barras con el siguiente codigo:     Barcode codigo = new Barcode();
                codigo.IncludeLabel = true;
                codigo.Alignment = AlignmentPositions.CENTER;
                codigo.LabelFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 9, FontStyle.Regular);

                Image img = codigo.Encode(TYPE.CODE128, barCode, Color.Black, Color.White, 200, 70);

                pictureBox1.Image = img;

Comment: O sea seria el estandart Code128

Comment: Hay un ejemplo similar a lo que necesitas hacer de un codigo QR, revisa este [link](https://estradawebgroup.com/Post/-Como-generar-codigos-QR-con-ASP-NET-MVC-/4238) te va ser de ayuda

Comment: un modo sencillo y rapido es que instales el Barcode39 en la computadora donde instalaras el sistema y en el campo donde quieres que se visualize el codigo de barras insertes una funcio asi ="*" & Fields!TUDATA.Value & "*" con esto coviertes tu data a codigo de barras en el rdlc, lleva un asterico entre las comillas